# Getting InvalidOperationException when using PerformanceCounters

Tags: c#, performancecounter

Getting:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.dll

Additional information:

> Category does not exist.

The code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
    PerformanceCounter ramCounter;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int timeX = 0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
        cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
        cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
        cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";


        float cpuUsage = 0.00F;
        cpuCounter.NextValue();
        cpuUsage = cpuCounter.NextValue();
        textBox1.Text = cpuUsage.ToString();


        ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
        float ram = ramCounter.NextValue();
        textBox2.Text = ram.ToString();

        chart1.Series["CPU Usage"].Points.AddXY(timeX, (int)cpuUsage);
        chart2.Series["Memory Use"].Points.AddXY(timeX, (int)ram);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       timer1.Start();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}
}
```

Getting errors on every `.nextValue();`

I have tried adding `Processor Information` in `CategoryName`, but doesn't help either.

EDIT:
@Jim this is my code after making your changes :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication12
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
    PerformanceCounter ramCounter;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InitializeCounters();
    }

    private void InitializeCounters()
    {
        cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
        cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
        cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
        cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

       // ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
    }

    int timeX = 0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float cpuUsage = 0.00F;
        cpuUsage = cpuCounter.NextValue();
        textBox1.Text = cpuUsage.ToString();

        float ram = ramCounter.NextValue();
        textBox2.Text = ram.ToString();

        // Your chart stuff
        //chart1.Series["CPU Usage"].Points.AddXY(timeX, (int)cpuUsage);
        //chart2.Series["Memory Use"].Points.AddXY(timeX, (int)ram);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you at least give us the stack trace and explain a little what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating new performance counters every time the timer ticks, you only need to **initialize** the counters **once**.

## Form1 Code Behind

```
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;   
PerformanceCounter ramCounter;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    InitializeCounters();
}

private void InitializeCounters()
{
    cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
    cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
    cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
    cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

    ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
}

int timeX = 0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    float cpuUsage = 0.00F;
    cpuUsage = cpuCounter.NextValue();
    textBox1.Text = cpuUsage.ToString();
   
    float ram = ramCounter.NextValue();
    textBox2.Text = ram.ToString();

    // Your chart stuff
    //chart1.Series["CPU Usage"].Points.AddXY(timeX, (int)cpuUsage);
    //chart2.Series["Memory Use"].Points.AddXY(timeX, (int)ram);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
}
```

**Side note:**

Also `Dispose` the counters when not using them anymore. Maybe on Form Closing event.

```
cpuCounter.Dispose();
ramCounter.Dispose();
```

---

## Result

[image]

---

## Case of an error

If my example still throws an error, this is most probably because one or more performance counters on your system are corrupted.

**Rebuild all performance counters:**

- Open command prompt (with Admin privileges)
- Run command: `lodctr /R`

The message:

> Info: Successfully rebuilt performance counter setting ...

will appear on success.

In case you receive the message:

> Unable to rebuild performance counter setting from system backup store, error code is 2

Possible solutions:

- Close all running programs
- Make sure you use `lodctr /R` with uppercase `R`
- If in directory system32 move to directory SysWOW64 (with cd.. > cd syswow64) and retry the `lodctr /R` command in this directory

Comment: i tried what you said and now i'm getting a .NullReferenceException and a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: @Commongrate the example I made will run out of the box. Try to make a new winforms project and add the code exactly like mine for testing. (Don't foget to call `InitializeCounters();` to initialize the counters. The method is called in my example in the Form constructor.

Comment: i copied your code, added everything and ran it, on the                              ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes"); line i got the same "cat does not exist" error , so i commented that and ran it, it ran , but when i click on button 1 it doesn't trigger an event and the textbox is empty

Comment: edited the post

Comment: @Commongrate i've made an edit myself, and added *case of an error*, try to rebuild the performance counters.

Comment: It WORKED, thanks so much for the help. I was wondering why it was working for my friend but not for me.

Comment: @Commongrate your welcome. If my answer helped you and was correct, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a category before using PerformanceCounter. More details and example in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
const String categoryName = "Processor";
const String counterName = "% Processor Time";

if ( !PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(categoryName) ) 
{
    CounterCreationDataCollection CCDC = new CounterCreationDataCollection();

    // Add the counter.
    CounterCreationData ETimeData = new CounterCreationData();
    ETimeData.CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.ElapsedTime;
    ETimeData.CounterName = counterName;
    CCDC.Add(ETimeData);       

    // Create the category.
    PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(categoryName,
            "Demonstrates ElapsedTime performance counter usage.",
        PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance, CCDC);
}
```